# Exclude Field If It Has Duplicates

Tags: mongodb

I am using MongoDB as my database. I have 52 Fields/BsonElement/FieldNames in each document. In my collection, contains millions of documents.

My app, using .NET, has a combobox/dropdown control that lets a user pick a unique primary key/field. I  want to know how to check if a field has any duplicate values. If there is, I will not include this in my combobox control.

Comment: Post your collections sample document.

Comment: [Image Reference](https://ibb.co/hiYpvb)

Comment: I've added an answer for how to query it, but building up the query in .NET I'd need to see how you use the driver.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could just use a groupby within an aggregate pipeline counting all unique fields then compare them to the total documents.

Say we have the following data:

```
[
  {
    "_id":ObjectId("59dc805cf51b821565695ec8"),
    "isDeleted": false,
    "salutation": "Mr.",
    "firstName": "Kevin",
    "lastName" : "Smith"
  },{
    "_id":ObjectId("59dc80d5f51b821565695ec9"),
    "isDeleted": true,
    "salutation": "Miss",
    "firstName": "Helen",
    "lastName" : "Smith"
  },{
    "_id":ObjectId("59dc80dff51b821565695eca"),
    "isDeleted": false,
    "salutation": "Mr.",
    "firstName": "Joe",
    "lastName" : "Bloggs"
  }
]
```

We could then run the following query:

```
db.test.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id : null,
      total: {$sum: 1},
      isDeleted: {$addToSet: "$isDeleted"},
      salutation:  {$addToSet: "$salutation"},
      firstName: {$addToSet: "$firstName"},
      lastName: {$addToSet : "$lastName"},
    },
  },{
    $project: {
      isDeleted: { $eq: [ "$total", {$size: "$isDeleted"} ]},
      salutation: { $eq: [ "$total", {$size: "$salutation"} ]},
      firstName: { $eq: [ "$total", {$size: "$firstName"} ]},
      lastName: { $eq: [ "$total", {$size: "$lastName"} ]}
    }
  }
]);
```

Which would return us a document with all the possible values for each field:

```
{
        "_id" : null,
        "isDeleted" : false,
        "salutation" : false,
        "firstName" : true,
        "lastName" : false
}
```

Comment: This will get the unique values of a certain field, right? I think, so..

What I want to check is to know if a field as a duplicate values. If all values/data of field are unique, then I will include this field as my primary key in the Combo Box.

Comment: altered a bit to just count the results :)

Comment: Let me try this on .NET, Kevin. It might take a while. I am not that familiar with the MongoDB methods. Appreciate the help.

Comment: Just to verify, for the result of `firstName`, if it is true - what it means is that all values of `firstName` are all unique, right? Else, `firstName` has a duplicate value?

Comment: Yeah if the field is `true` then all values are unique. we should rename them to more sensible names

Answer (score 0):

Try [distinct](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.distinct/) this will help us in picking only the unique values

For example, if there is a Country Drop down(Combo box), then the query to retrieve the unique values of Country is

```
db.collection.distinct("Country")
```

Comment: I am not trying to get the unique values of a field. What I am trying to put on my lists are fields - where all the values of each field are unique.

Comment: I think I am going to run distinct first then if it is equals to collection.count, then all values are unique?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Kevin Smith for his answer I was able to finish it. Cheers!~

`.NET` equivalent:

```
`Dim Aggregate = Collection.Aggregate.
     Group(New BsonDocument From {
         {"_id", BsonNull.Value},
         {"total", New BsonDocument From {
             {"$sum", 1}}},
         {"isDeleted", New BsonDocument From {
             {"$addToSet", "$isDeleted"}}}}
).
Project(
    New BsonDocument From {
        {"isDeleted", New BsonDocument From {
            {"$eq", New BsonArray From {
                "$total", New BsonDocument From {
                    {"$size", "$isDeleted"}}}}}}}
)`
```